# Create snippet/live template from last row or copy paste?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

Is there a way to create your own snippet/live templates that takes the latest created variable or the latest that is copied? I know how to make regular "hardcoded" snippets but not dynamic ones.

Ex:

```
const amount = 1000;
log -> press tab (snippet) -> console.log("amount: ", amount) // "amount: 1000"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Postfix completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#postfix_completion) (**File | Settings | Editor | General | Postfix Completion**) with the following template text:

```
console.log("$EXPR$: ", $EXPR$) // "$EXPR$: $END$"
```

If you call the template 'logf', the invocation in the editor will look like this:

```
const amount = 1000;
amount.logf -> press TAB -> console.log("amount: ", amount) // "amount: "
```

The value in the comment will have to be entered manually (maybe there's a way to script it, idk). The cursor will be placed at the `$END$`'s position: right before the last double-quote.

You can also look into the ['Custom Postfix Templates'](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9862-custom-postfix-templates) unofficial plugin for IDEA.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is a `clipboard()` function you may use in live templates.

Here are the steps;

1. Go into live templates - create a new one
2. Abbreviation: `log`
3. Template text: `console.log($clipboard$);`
4. Click `Edit variables`
5. name: `clipboard` expression: `clipboard()` - click ok
6. Choose applicable context.

When you copy some text(such as `'something'`) before typing `log`, it is going to print `console.log('something');` when you `type + tab`

Comment: Works perfect! Ended up using it this way. Thanks!  `console.log('$clipboard$: ', $clipboard$);´